# Automatically assign a customer attribute based on that customer's entity ID during the account creation process?

Tags: attributes, customer, enterprise-1.13

Example:  Customer is created with entity_id of 115.  Customer attribute custom_id is assigned with a prefix of "HH" followed by the entity_id.  So the custom_id is "HH115".  I assume this would be done with an observer and then happen on the before save of the customer account.  Though, i don't know how to get access to the entity_id before the account is actually created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object,`It is not possible`

First of all ,`entity_id is auto increment field which value is  assigned  to Object after any Object Save`.
Magento did not provide to created this field to before save.

If Magento  is provide this feature then `this auto increment field  value is automatically increase in database whenever data is failed to submit`.
It will be better idea to `use after_save event`

Use Magento event  customer_save_after for that case

```
 <global>
       <events>
            <customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <your_define_event_name>
                        <class>youtmodulemodelname/observer</class>
                        <method>autosetCustomer</method>
                    </your_define_event_name>
                </observers>
       </events>
       </global>
```

Observer code:

```
public function autosetCustomer($observer) {


    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

     if ($customer->getOrigData('entity_id') || $customer->getCustomId()) {
         return $this;
    }
    $Obcustomer =  $observer->getCustomer();
    $customer->setYourCustomattbute('HH'.$customer->getId());
    // for faster save
     $customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($Obcustomer, 'youattribute_code');
   }
```

Comment: Why do you have `$Obcustomer = $observer->getCustomerAddress();` Shouldn't that be `$Obcustomer = $observer->getCustomer();` ?

Comment: Ah, an after_save would work perfectly.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Give me a sec to try it out!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have access to the `entity_id`  before the account is created.
What I don't understand is why you need this. As long as the attribute value is going to be `HH{entity_id}`, why not just create a method in one of your helpers that will retrieve that value when you need it.
Something like this:

```
function getSomeCustomerValue($customer) {
    if (!$customer->getId()) {
         return '';
    }
    return 'HH'.$customer->getId();
}
```

This way you don't need a new attribute and you don't need to save anything in the db.

But if you insist on having the attribute you need to observe the event `customer_save_after` to make sure you have the `entity_id` available.

And the method goes something like this (untested code):

```
public function afterSaveCustomer($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    //if the entity has an original id or if the 'custom_id' is set do nothing
    //this means it's either update or you already set the custom id
    if ($customer->getOrigData('entity_id') || $customer->getCustomId()) {
         return $this;
    }
    //otherwise, generate the custom id and save the customer
    $customer->setCustomId('HH'.$customer->getId());
    $customer->save();
}
```

Comment: ,is it good idea to use save() function?

Comment: @AmitBera. It's never a good idea to use `save` :). I added it here of the top of my head. I guess the way you do it with `saveAttribute` should be faster and safer.

Comment: The reason this attribute has to exist is because of an arcane connection to an ERP system that requires a unique identifier.  The constraints of the system leave me with this odd option.

Comment: then just send to the ERP the customer id. That should be unique.

Comment: It requires a store based prefix.  This is a requirement of their legacy process.  I've already suggested that they add the prefix on their end based on the entity_id I send them.  It would be less overhead on everyone's part.  Believe me, I am not excited about adding a redundant attribute to every customer account.